# Why isn't session id persisting in same domain

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am noticing that my php session id changes when I go from

https://www.mathtutortime.com/tutor/tutor to https://www.mathtutortime.com/account/get_tutoring/lobby.html.

It works just fine if I am going from

https://www.mathtutortime.com/account/ to https://www.mathtutortime.com/account/get_tutoring/lobby.html.

I thought session id's only aren't preserved on different domains.

my code at https://www.mathtutortime.com/tutor/tutor has session information that I stored already in

https://www.mathtutortime.com/tutor. The code in https://www.mathtutortime.com/tutor/tutor is:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script>
        window.location.replace("https://www.mathtutortime.com/account/get_tutoring/lobby.html")
    </script>

    </head>


    <body>



    </body>

</html>
```

at lobby.html, I have:

```
<?php session_start();
echo session_id();
if($_SESSION['loggedin'])
{
    echo "yelo";
    if(!$_SESSION['tutor'] && $_SESSION['minutes'] > 0)
    {
```

...

```
?>
```

Now, if I reload lobby.html after the redirect, the session id seems to reset back to what it was. Meaning it works after reloading the page. I think this because I am able to get past the

```
if($_SESSION['loggedin'])
```

section in lobby.html, and I can see the session ID change when I echo it out.

Because of this, I think the session information really does persist, but has a lapse only when I redirect using window.location.replace, etc. But I have no idea why.

Thanks for assistance.

Comment: It looks like you have some *whitespace* before your 1st `session_start()`. Any output rendered before `session_start()` *will* make the call fail.

Comment: I checked. That was just a typo on here. I changed it on here to what the code really is.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
    <?php session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
```

To become this, so that there is no whitespace (or any other character) that gets rendered before session_start().

```
<?php session_start();
?><!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
```

Your !doctype should have no preceding whitespace too, though wouldnt be the problem.

Comment: I checked. That was just a typo on here. I changed it on here to what the code really is.

Answer (score 0):

Really strange, now it works. I just reset my history/cookies. I did have session_start() on a new line, so that may have fixed it. But the fact that it was fixed only was revealed after deleting my cookies/history. Anyways, thanks for those that answered!.

Comment: Wasn't too strange. Although whats strange is you didnt upvote me.